# Why is $(5y^4 -1)^{-1} $ undefined for $y = \pm i(5)^{-1/4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I do not understand why $\frac{1}{5y^4 -1}$ is undefined for $y=\pm i{5^{-1/4}}.$

What I tried:
$\frac{1}{5y^4 -1}$ is undefined for any y satisfying $${5y^4 -1}=0.$$
$$y^4 = \frac{1}{5}$$ 
$$y = \pm 5^{-1/4}$$ 
Where does the $i$ come from?

Comment: Those are the 2 real roots you found.  The ones you're questioning are the 2 imaginary roots.

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't yet studied complex numbers, right? If this is true then this exercise isn't for you.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\pm i\frac1{\sqrt[4]5}\implies y^4=\frac15\implies 5y^4-1=0 $$

and that's the reason the expression isn't defined at the above values of $\;y\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

$$y^4 = \frac15 =\frac15 \exp(2 \pi ni), n=0,1,2,3.$$

Hence $$y= 5^{-1/4}\exp \left(\frac{\pi n i}{2}\right), n=0,1,2,3.$$

That is $y$ is undefined for $$y=5^{-1/4}, 5^{-1/4}i,-5^{-1/4},-5^{-1/4}i.$$